# zsh command substitution fails when assigned to LINES

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

Why does this fail for zsh?

```
bash-3.2$ FILENAME="/Users/john/Desktop/hash.txt"
bash-3.2$ LINES=$(cat $FILENAME)
bash-3.2$ echo $LINES
ccf09b34dd38f383ce0eb37efbda0bfc546bb562 b78ae347a7039aeb0643f7534300b7549c2cd9f4
```

using zsh...

```
11/17/21_2:17:39 /Users/john
$ FILENAME="/Users/john/Desktop/hash.txt"

11/17/21_2:17:47 /Users/john
$ LINES=$(cat $FILENAME)
zsh: bad math expression: operator expected at `b78ae347a7...'

11/17/21_2:24:07 /Users/john
$ LINES=$(`cat $FILENAME`) 
zsh: command not found: ccf09b34dd38f383ce0eb37efbda0bfc546bb562

11/17/21_2:26:34 /Users/john
$ LINES=`$(cat $FILENAME)` 
zsh: command not found: ccf09b34dd38f383ce0eb37efbda0bfc546bb562

11/17/21_2:26:40 /Users/john
$ LINES=`$(cat "$FILENAME")`
zsh: command not found: ccf09b34dd38f383ce0eb37efbda0bfc546bb562

11/17/21_2:28:30 /Users/john
$ LINES="$(`cat $FILENAME`)"
zsh: command not found: ccf09b34dd38f383ce0eb37efbda0bfc546bb562
```

giving up and begging for help

Comment: `LINES` seems to be a reserved word in `zsh`, it works with other names

Comment: @nohillside how did you determine this? Is there an indication in the error message or just trial and error? Is there a list of reserved words for zsh?

Comment: I just tried with another variable, there it worked. Then I tried `LINES='HELLO WORLD'` and got the same error as you do. `LINES='1 + 2'` sets LINES to 3. I rarely use `zsh` so I don't really know what's going on here.

Comment: `set | grep LINE` gives me `LINES=25` with `bash` on 10.14. It means the number of lines in the console window.  So, *how to determine this* would be to do `set` and see what is already set in the shell, and `env` to see what is already exported by the shell. I'm assuming (sorry) that `zsh` has `set` and `env` (probably all shells I've used in the last 40 year have). A *list of reserved words* should be in the documentation for `zsh`. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the variable name. `LINES` is one of the variables with a conventional meaning. Its meaning is to convey the number of lines in a terminal. There is a similar variable `COLUMNS`.

One of the jobs of an interactive shell is to update these two variables when the terminal is resized. Both bash and zsh do this. Even in bash, while `LINES=$(…)` does work, the value will be overwritten if you resize the terminal.

In zsh, additionally, `LINES` and `COLUMNS` are declared as integer variables (which makes perfect sense given their purpose). So if you try to assign to them, the string that you assign is interpreted as an arithmetic expression, hence the error if you try to assign a string that isn't a valid arithmetic expression. You can see that the variable is declared as an integer with [`typeset`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-typeset):

```
% typeset -p LINES
typeset -i10 LINES=25
```

`-i` indicates an integer variable, `10` forces it to be represented in base 10 (which is the default anyway).

Don't use variables whose names are used by your shell, such as `PATH`, `LINES`, `PS1`, etc. Unfortunately, there's no namespace for shell or environment variables: you have to share. The zsh manual lists the [variables that zsh sets](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell) and the [variables that zsh uses if the user sets them](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell). The bash manual has a [list of variables that it uses or sets](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Variables).

There is a widespread convention that environment variables and variables that have some meaning to the shell are in all uppercase. But zsh also uses some all-lowercase variables.